# Async function passed as prop into React component causing @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-functional-component, asynchronous-javascript

I have the following asynchronous *submitNewPatient* function which is throwing *@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises* error message from elint. Is it possible to adjust the function such that it removes this error?

```
const submitNewPatient = async (values: PatientFormValues) => {
    try {
      const { data: newPatient } = await axios.post<Patient>(
        `${apiBaseUrl}/patients`,
        values
      );
      dispatch({ type: "ADD_PATIENT", payload: newPatient });
      closeModal();
    } catch (e: unknown) {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(e)) {
        console.error(e?.response?.data || "Unrecognized axios error");
        setError(
          String(e?.response?.data?.error) || "Unrecognized axios error"
        );
      } else {
        console.error("Unknown error", e);
        setError("Unknown error");
      }
    }
  };
```

Component used to pass function as a prop:

```
<AddPatientModal
        modalOpen={modalOpen}
        onSubmit={submitNewPatient}
        error={error}
        onClose={closeModal}
      />
```

I have also tried the following which removes the eslint error message based. However, seems like I am not entering the async code block (perhaps not triggering the async() function):

```
  const submitNewPatient = (values: PatientFormValues) => {
    async () => {
      try {
        const { data: newPatient } = await axios.post<Patient>(
          `${apiBaseUrl}/patients`,
          values
        );
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_PATIENT", payload: newPatient });
        closeModal();
      } catch (e: unknown) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(e)) {
          console.error(e?.response?.data || "Unrecognized axios error");
          setError(
            String(e?.response?.data?.error) || "Unrecognized axios error"
          );
        } else {
          console.error("Unknown error", e);
          setError("Unknown error");
        }
      }
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `async` code block syntax. You need it to make it an **IIFE** (Immediately-invoked Function Expression for it to be executed immediately.

```
(async () => {
    await someAsyncFunction();
})();
```

Your `submitNewPatient` becomes -

```
const submitNewPatient = (values: PatientFormValues) => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const { data: newPatient } = await axios.post<Patient>(
          `${apiBaseUrl}/patients`,
          values
        );
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_PATIENT", payload: newPatient });
        closeModal();
      } catch (e: unknown) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(e)) {
          console.error(e?.response?.data || "Unrecognized axios error");
          setError(
            String(e?.response?.data?.error) || "Unrecognized axios error"
          );
        } else {
          console.error("Unknown error", e);
          setError("Unknown error");
        }
      }
    })();
  };
```

Comment: Thanks @Aseem 
I tried this method however I am required to append a .catch() in addition to the existing catch block already implemented. Apart from that, the function seems to working as expected.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is not in your code but in the ESLint rule or the ESLint config. React 17 and later can handle async functions as event handlers.

The IIFE gets rid of the ESLint error but the error should not appear in the first place. Unless you are using React 16 or earlier.

There was a lengthy discussion about the rule on [Github](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4619).

The proposed [solution](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/4623) is to remove the check for attributes or arguments:

```
{
  "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
    "error",
    {"checksVoidReturn": {"attributes": false}}
  ]
}
```

https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-misused-promises/

Comment: I am using react 18 but facing with this issue. However, the solution works. But is the any side effect of this?